# Formatting issue with enumerating summation formulae

Tags: math-mode, enumerate

I have the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLApn.jpg) when I try to create an enumeration of my summation formulae for class. I am trying to replicate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5ZD.jpg) but I am having issues with the size of the summation matching the line height as summations are quite tall.

They seem to centre regardless of my attempts to flush them left.

Here's my code so far:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1 = n \]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = 1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\approx \frac{1}{2}n^2\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\approx \frac{1}{3}n^3\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k = 1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k = \frac{1}{k+1}n^k+1\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=0}^{n} a^i = 1+a + ... + a^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}(a\neq 1); \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i = 1\cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + ... + n2^n = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + ...+...\frac{1}{n}\approx \text{ln n + }\gamma\text{, where} \gamma \approx \text{0.5772...(Euler's Constant)}\]
    \item \[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{lg i} \approx \text{n lg n}\]
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the features of `enumitem` to add `\displaystyle` to all math formulas, otherwise you should add it manually in each `$...$`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % more generous margins
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.},before=\everymath{\displaystyle}]
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1 = n$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = 1 + 2 + \dots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \approx \frac{1}{2}n^2$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\approx \frac{1}{3}n^3$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k = 1^k + 2^k + \dots + n^k = \frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1}$
\item $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^i = 1+a + \dots + a^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}(a\neq 1)$; \quad $\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i = 1\cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + \dots + n \cdot 2^n = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}\approx \ln n + \gamma$, where $\gamma \approx 0.5772\dots$ (Euler's Constant)
\item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lg i \approx n \lg n$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Miscellaneous comments:

- `amsmath` is not really necessary here but should be anyway loaded any time your math formulas contain something more than `1+1=2`.
- Don't write an ellipsis with three dots `...`, but uses the macro `\dots`. With `amsmath` this will automatically choose which version is best.
- `\text` is for text; math operators like the logarithm should be typed as  `\ln`, `\lg`.

Comment: isn't `\log` more traditional for `log`? And +1 for at really good answer.

Comment: @daleif It surely is, and to be honest I was quite surprised to find out that `\lg` is already predefined. But hey, the linked picture contains `lg` so I just kept it.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `\lg` before, and I've been at this UNI now for 25 years (student and IT employee)

Comment: Great. I found this very thorough. I appreciated the extra math formatting tips (ln, log...). I have to follow strict formatting guidelines for assignments, but they dont teach us LaTex in the course, sigh... +1, marked as accepted solution, thank you!

Comment: I just used this answer again, and didn't realised I'd viewed it before and even went as far as to comment and upvote. Making notes for comp, and this saved me on a formatting issue once again... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mathlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mathlist,1]{label={\arabic*.}}


\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1 = n$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = 1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\approx \frac{1}{2}n^2$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\approx \frac{1}{3}n^3$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k = 1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k = \frac{1}{k+1}n^k+1$
    \item $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^i = 1+a + ... + a^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}(a\neq 1); \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i = 1\cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + ... + n2^n = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + ...+...\frac{1}{n}\approx \text{ln n + }\gamma\text{, where} \gamma \approx \text{0.5772...(Euler's Constant)}$
    \item $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{lg i} \approx \text{n lg n}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]

Comment: Thankyou for such a detailed answer. I have a specific format to follow for my course, where the n is above the summation and the i=1 is below it (not in line). However, you helped me solve the formatting issue with the margins and enumerate.